# How can I update the password of a password protected .7z archive?

Tags: command-line, passwords, 7-zip

How can I update the password of a password protected .7z archive using the command line ?

I have a couple of big 7z archives (several hundred Gb) and would like to strengthen the passwords by updating them, hopefully without having to unzip / rezip the whole set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to the nature of 7zip, you are not able to do this, unless you want to unzip/rezip. The author of the application has said so on their forums.

[Proof](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5bf0b627/#d065)

Answer (score 3):

The passwords are not really passwords but the seed to derive the encryption key. So, what you want to do is changing the encryption key and that means decrypting an reencrypting.